# Error: "'if' cannot be used as a variable or function name" appeared. I cant undarstand why

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Here's some scripting I did in PineScript. It doesn't compile because of

> 'if' cannot be used as a variable or function name.

```
//@version=5
strategy
```

```
rsi = ta.rsi(price, ShortLength)
vrsi1 = ta.rsi(price, LongLength)
co = ta.crossover(vrsi, overSold)
co1 = vrsi1-vrsi<=betweenbuy
co2 = vrsi1<vrsi1BottomBorder
barsSinceLastEntry=1
barsSinceLastEntry := strategy.opentrades > 0 ? bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1) : na
cu = ta.crossunder(vrsi, overBought)
cu1 = vrsi-vrsi1<=betweensell
cu2 = vrsi-vrsi1<=betweensell+(betweensell*barsSinceLastEntry/barsbetween)
cu3 = vrsi1>vrsi1TopBorder
rco = ta.crossunder (vrsi, overSold)
rco1 = ta.crossunder (vrsi1, vrsi1BottomBorder)

rcu = ta.crossover (vrsi, overBought)
rcu1 = ta.crossunder(vrsi1, vrsi1TopBorder)

//Creating buy/sell logic
if (not na(vrsi))
    if (co and co1 and co2 and inTradeWindow)
        strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, comment="Buy")
     if (rco and rco1 and inTradeWindow)
          strategy.entry("Buy1", strategy.long, comment="Buy1")
    if (barsSinceLastEntry<barsbetween)
        if (inTradeWindow and cu and cu1 and cu3)
            strategy.exit("exit", "Buy",profit = profitnumber, loss = lossnumber)
    else if (barsSinceLastEntry>=barsbetween)
        if (inTradeWindow and cu and cu2 and cu3)
            strategy.exit("exit", "Buy",profit = profitnumber, loss = lossnumber)     
     if (rcu and rcu1 and inTradeWindow)
          strategy.exit("exit", "Buy1",profit = profitnumber, loss = lossnumber)
```

But it compiles perfectly with two commented blocks (As it was before my last changes).

```
/Creating buy/sell logic
if (not na(vrsi))
    if (co and co1 and co2 and inTradeWindow)
        strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, comment="Buy")
//     if (rco and rco1 and inTradeWindow)
//          strategy.entry("Buy1", strategy.long, comment="Buy1")
    if (barsSinceLastEntry<barsbetween)
        if (inTradeWindow and cu and cu1 and cu3)
            strategy.exit("exit", "Buy",profit = profitnumber, loss = lossnumber)
    else if (barsSinceLastEntry>=barsbetween)
        if (inTradeWindow and cu and cu2 and cu3)
            strategy.exit("exit", "Buy",profit = profitnumber, loss = lossnumber)     
//     if (rcu and rcu1 and inTradeWindow)
//          strategy.exit("exit", "Buy1",profit = profitnumber, loss = lossnumber)
```

Also I tried to compile it in reverse (like switch commented/non-commented). aaaand... it does not.

What's wrong here? And how to fix it?

When I started, it seemed to be super simple: a few variables and two logical blocks, the same structure as blocks I used before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spacing is off. You need your indents to be 4 spaces, you had some random ones at 5.

I can't tell if your script will compile though because you have undeclared identifiers when I use the code you provided. Anyways here's your code with the correct spacing on this section.

```
if (not na(vrsi))
    if (co and co1 and co2 and inTradeWindow)
        strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, comment="Buy")
    if (rco and rco1 and inTradeWindow)
        strategy.entry("Buy1", strategy.long, comment="Buy1")
    if (barsSinceLastEntry<barsbetween)
        if (inTradeWindow and cu and cu1 and cu3)
            strategy.exit("exit", "Buy",profit = profitnumber, loss = lossnumber)
    else if (barsSinceLastEntry>=barsbetween)
        if (inTradeWindow and cu and cu2 and cu3)
            strategy.exit("exit", "Buy",profit = profitnumber, loss = lossnumber)     
    if (rcu and rcu1 and inTradeWindow)
        strategy.exit("exit", "Buy1",profit = profitnumber, loss = lossnumber)
```

Comment: @smashpalooza thanks for help, it has compiled.
But there are still a few things I don't understand, could you please clarify them for me?
I used Tab as documentation said. And just now I found that in some of my lines tabs transformed into 5 spaces for some reason. Is that usually happens in this editor or I did something wrong? Look: https://skr.sh/vKQQvnWKS3R
There are screencast where I cleared all the spaces before my code on the line 57, used tab but it transformed in 5 spaces again. That seems to be not okay. D'you know why is that happens like this?

Comment: I think it is an error in TV, I have had that randomly happen as well on certain codes. I haven't found out why it happens or a solution other than having to manually count 4 spaces every time. I hope they fix it